# How to setup firewall ports via logon script

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, vnc, windows-domain

I work as IT suport for public service. We use domain controller and logon scripts. These scripts are pretty helpful, since they can automatically install printers and add network folders as local drives.

We use VNC to access user's computers so we can give them suport. In some cases their Windows Firewall is active, and the VNC inbound/outbound ports are configured and work pretty fine. In many other cases, we have to ask people to disable their firewall. That's the practice people do here, and they usually don't ask people to enable the firewall again. Since this is a hazard, I'd like to know if are there any commands we can run on these logon scripts so the ports are automatically configured in all machines and we don't have to ask people to run on network without firewall.

Best.

Comment: besides david postil's answer, of  netsh to open and close ports. Another option you can try is the reverse connection.. the "server" in the sense of the side that sends its screen, the side that responds to requests to move the mouse cursor.. the side that traditionally listens.. That side, can initiate a connection to a listening viewer. https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/af1050529.html    and https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/aj1077505.html  So the techie opens the port on his machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I setup firewall ports using a script

`netsh` can be used to configure the Windows firewall.

In particular `netsh advfirewall ...`

> Enable and delete a port: One of the most common things you need to do with Windows Firewall is open ports that are used by different programs. The following examples show how to use netsh to create a rule to open and then close port 1433, which is used by Microsoft SQL Server:

Source [NETSH (Network Shell) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)

---

#### Example  - Open/Close Ports

Open port:

```
 netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My App" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1433
```

Close port:

```
 netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="My App" protocol=tcp localport=1433
```

Source [Top 10: Windows Firewall Netsh Commands](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/top-10-windows-firewall-netsh-commands)

---

#### Example - Enable/Disable Program

You can also add rule rules that use just the program path. In this case you don't need to specify the ports.

Enable Program:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My App" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe" enable=yes
```

Disable Program:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="My App" program="C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe"
```

Source [How to use the "netsh advfirewall firewall" context instead of the "netsh firewall" context to control Windows Firewall behavior in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947709)

Comment: I want to do it to enable VNC which uses ports ranging from 5800 to 5900. Is there a way to do it - open ports - for a range?

Comment: According to [How do I allow connections through my firewall?](https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/269/12/how-do-i-allow-connections-through-my-firewall) you only need to allow a single port, 5900

Comment: What's better, to refer to the port or refer to the software? Example, do I put port 5900 protocol any inbound ou it is better to put c:\program files\ubnba\... ? And how do I do to test if the rule worked? I should look for the rule on any computer? Does the server enforce the rule only the first time the user authenticates or every time he or she does?

Comment: @ViníciusSimões Just follow the instruction in the answer (with the appropriate port number). The name of program doesn't matter it's just a name for the rule. The rule is only used if there is inbound traffic on that port (but it is open all the time unless you close it). If it doesn't work you won't be able to remote in ...

Comment: What I would like to know is if I put the name of the software for which I want to open the port the exception rule will work. And if it is better policy to put the port number or the software path. We ensure all client computers have UltraVNC installed, so I would like to know if I put the path it would somehow allow traffic exclusively to the application.

Comment: I tested the rule and in many cases I saw it worked. I just checked the exception rules on Windows and my rule name was there present. But in one case it still didn't allow me to connect to it. Do you know a way to troubleshoot and find the reason?

Comment: @DavidPostill  I don't think it's just a name. I think if you add the program then whatever port it listens on is opened.

Comment: @barlop `name` is required and is just a string (the name of the rule), there is an optional `program=...` parameter which is not the same as name. I will update the answer with some examples using `program...`

Comment: @ViníciusSimões If you use the path it will allow the whole application (so ports are not required). Answer updated.